# Replace characters in string from dictionary mapping

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

I'm pretty new to python, so forgive me if I am missing an obvious built-in function.

I have a dictionary mapping I generated like the following:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(restAlphaSet,list(item)))
```

where restAlphaSet it a string and list(item) is list converted iteration

I am trying to use this to replace all the characters in my string.  I found a replaceAll function online that looks like the following:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    if i != j:
        text = text.replace(i, j)
return text
```

Unfortunately, this is flawed as if the mapping has a->b, b->a, then nothing would get changed as the b's would be changed back to the a's.

I found the translate function, but it doesn't accept a dictionary input.

Comment: What about removing the `b -> a` mappings?

Comment: There's a syntax error in your example function. `If i!=j` needs a colon at the end, else it will generate a SyntaxError.

Comment: First it will fail with `IndentationError` :)

Comment: its very similar to a cryptogram.  So letters can be mapped to any other letter (no dupliactes), I just need an order independent function. And ya I copied bad, i'll add colon

Comment: `translate` does accept dicts if applied to unicode objects  (see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: Who cares if translate accepts ``dict``s? You made a ``dict`` because that was what you needed, if you don't, just use your lists to [construct a translation table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10155826/722121).

Answer (score 8):

Translations are way faster.

```
>>> import string
>>> text.translate(string.maketrans("".join(restAlphaSet),"".join(item)))
```

Comment: it seems the translate function has the same issue as before where it is changing characters back to what they were.

Comment: @NickG mm.. it must be an issue with your code, post it so that we can figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Py 3.x?, sure 3.9+: str.maketrans (no need to import).

Answer (score 4):

You are overlooking the [translate](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) function. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm) for a usage example.

Comment: str.maketrans (don't import: string)